# Turn Screen Off using proximity sensor

Tags: android

I have an issue when using the proximity sensor to turn the screen off. When My Device is using the SDK version 21 or upper I can use this code to turn off the Screen when a user put the phone near something. (Capturing the events of the SensorEventListener)

```
public void turnOnScreen(){
    // turn on screen
    Log.v("ProximityActivity", "ON!");
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}

@TargetApi(21) //Suppress lint error for PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK
public void turnOffScreen(){
    // turn off screen
    Log.v("ProximityActivity", "OFF!");
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}
```

Now, the problem is that I don't know how to get the same behavior before API 21. I would like to put the screen in Black and disable all the events on it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi , have you solved your question ? If yes , please share your answer .
Because I have same problem here.Thx